# Apache POI Conditional Formatting for date(MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM) greater than 14:00

Tags: java, apache-poi, conditional-formatting

I'm doing an automation of reading the data from csv and updating in a consolidated xlsx file (which is having multiple sheets around 40 sheets) on a daily basis. the final part pending for automation is conditional formatting which is being done manually.

I would like to know the formula to be used for conditional formatting using Apache POI.

in a cell im having date format as  "3/15/2020 15:19" i want to highlight it with light red background and dark red font.

Comment: Can you show your code and indicate a problem?

Comment: i've started for conditional formatting. but no idea on it. just the below piece of code which was not even tested.
`SheetConditionalFormatting sheetCF = spreadSheet.getSheetConditionalFormatting();
       ConditionalFormattingRule rule1 = sheetCF.createConditionalFormattingRule("AND(A2-TODAY()>=0,A2-TODAY()<=30)");
          FontFormatting font = rule1.createFontFormatting();
          font.setFontStyle(false, true);
          font.setFontColorIndex(IndexedColors.RED.index);`

Comment: What formula would you use to do that in Excel itself? Figure out that, and then give Apache POI the same formula

Comment: while doing in excel, i'm not using any formula, just select 
Conditional Formatting --> Highlight cell rules --> Greater than --> 3/16/2020 14:00

Comment: Excel is probably turning that into a formula, maybe add that in Excel, open the file in Apache POI, and read back the formula there?